# (JAVA) How check status of Step in AWS EMR?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, emr

I am using Java EMR API to run pig job on EMR cluster. I am using following code to add Steps in JobFLow:

```
    String jobFlowId = "j-assdasd";
    AmazonElasticMapReduceClient client = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(
                    credentials);

    StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();


    StepConfig executePig = new StepConfig()
                    .withName("Execute Pig")
                    .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CANCEL_AND_WAIT)
                    .withHadoopJarStep(
                                    stepFactory
                                    .newRunPigScriptStep("s3://bucket/script/load.pig"));

    AddJobFlowStepsRequest pig = new AddJobFlowStepsRequest(jobFlowId)
                    .withSteps( executePig);
    AddJobFlowStepsResult result = client.addJobFlowSteps(pig);
```

How can i get the status of the "Execute Pig" status? I want to make program wait till the step finishes on EMR.

Comment: This really depends on what you need to do once the step is complete. If you only need to ensure that the step is complete before starting your next piece of code, you can do that [on the CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-wait-for-step.html), so I'll bet the java API has a method for this too (though I don't know it off-hand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it java:

```
   List<String> id = result.getStepIds();
   DescribeStepResult res = client.describeStep(new DescribeStepRequest().withStepId(id.get(0)));
   StepStatus status = res.getStep().getStatus();
   String stas = status.getState();
```

But, here we need to loop on status till its return completed.

Answer (score 0):

As Ajay mentioned on his own answer, there is a need for a loop to constantly check the statuses of the cluster, bootstrap actions, and steps. [This post](http://emrjavaapi.blogspot.com.es/2014/07/control-cluster-bootstrap-and-step.html) shows how to create such loop to keep the program inside of it until a certain status is reached.